Issues with darg & drop with FLatList in react-native
I'm working on a react-native + expo application. I have a screen Home with a fox template (.glb with react-three/fiber) in the middle and a Navbar at the bottom. I have a button in my Navbar which allows me to unfold a Modal (ClothesScreen) which takes up 30% of the bottom of the screen (enough to display content and to leave the fox visible in the background). In this Modal I have a FlatList of items. I'm trying to make an item from the FlatList draggable to the fox modele.
My problem: I use react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated to make my item draggable but when I drag my item outside the FlatList it goes below all the content. I tried to fix the problem using zIndex but it didn't work at all. I tried using Portals (@gorhom/portal) which fixed my problem but made my FlatList unusable because Portals seem to overload its style, displaying the items vertically when I want them horizontally . I haven't found a solution to correct this problem, does anyone have any ideas, whether on this style problem or this FlatList problem that we could resolve differently?éaéH
